# columns using bootstrap grid not displaying correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm having trouble getting columns to display correctly on a page, using bootstrap.  It seems to be set up correctly, but it is displaying vertically instead of side-by-side as I intend.  The pertinent code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col md 6">
                <h1 style="text-decoration: underline">A Message</h1>
                <h2>Some more information</h2>
                <img id="imageX" src="imageX.png" height="150" width="100"><h2>Signature</h2>
            </div>  
                <h2>Video Pre-Caption<h2>   
            <div class="col md 3">  
                <div>
                    <iframe width="250" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E__F5a2pQco" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col md 3">
                <div>
                    <iframe width="250" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ra-Cq19vBXA" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `-` (hyphen) character in between naming the bootstrap classes of your grid. Please try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Notice col*-*md*-*6 .* is for clarity-->
            <h1 style="text-decoration: underline">A Message</h1>
            <h2>Some more information</h2>
            <img id="imageX" src="imageX.png" height="150" width="100"><h2>Signature</h2>
        </div>  
            <h2>Video Pre-Caption<h2>   
        <div class="col-md-3">  
            <div>
                <iframe width="250" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E__F5a2pQco" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div>
                <iframe width="250" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ra-Cq19vBXA" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  It always seems to be something rather simple that I've missed - thank you for your help!